# Convert html list to xml through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am trying to convert the HTML input data added in list items into XML file. On button click opens a modal popup which will contain the xml data

```
<ul id="list">
            <li>
                <span class="name name-block">Hello</span><span>=</span><span class="name value-block">World</span>
                <span class="btn delete">Delete</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="name name-block">Happy</span><span>=</span><span class="name value-block">Coding</span>
                <span class="btn delete">Delete</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

My try

```
$(".show-xml").on("click", () => {
$("#dialog").dialog();
let xml = '<List>';
$("ul#list li").each(function(){
  const name = $(this).children('.name-block').val();
  const value = $(this).children(".value-block").val();
  if(name && value){
    xml += "<Item>\n";
    xml += "<Name>" + name + "</Name>\n";
    xml += "<Value>" + value + "</Value>\n";
    xml += "</Item>\n";
  }
}).appendTo('#dialog');
```

});

```
<List>
 <Item>
  <Name>Hello</Name>
  <Value>World</Value>
 </Item>
 <Item>
  <Name>Test Name</Name>
  <Value>Test Value</Value>
 </Item>
</List>
```

Comment: is that last snippet what your code produces? is it what you want? You haven't actually stated any "problem"

Comment: I'd recommend using a definition list rather than an unordered list. (`<dl>` instead of `ul`). That would be better for key/value pairs.

Comment: Maybe XSLT is better...

Comment: `<span>` elements don't have `value`s, use `.text()` instead of `.val()`.

Comment: Also, `$("ul#list li").each(....).appendTo('#dialog');` will append `ul#list li` to `#dialog` not the `xml` string.

Comment: I am a beginner with jquery so I'll try all the suggestions. Thank you all for helping out and pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is best and easy concept to convert `html to xml`.. no need to use `val().` instead of val() you need to use `.text() || .html()` working example as below

```js
 $('#go').click(function() {
    var xml = '<List>';
     $("ul#list li").each(function(){
      var name = $(this).children('.name-block').text();
      var value = $(this).children(".value-block").text();
      if(name && value){
        xml += "<Item>\n";
        xml += "<Name>" + name + "</Name>\n";
        xml += "<Value>" + value + "</Value>\n";
        xml += "</Item>\n";
      }
    });
    xml += "</list>"
    $('.modal-body').append(xml);
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
    console.log(xml)
    })
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-3">
        <button type="button" id="go" class="btn btn-primary">Open XML Modal Box</button>
      </div>
    </div>
<!--Modal if input is empty-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">you xml value printed below</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>

    <ul id="list">
                <li>
                    <span class="name name-block">Hello</span><span>=</span><span class="name value-block">World</span>
                    <span class="btn delete">Delete</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="name name-block">Happy</span><span>=</span><span class="name value-block">Coding</span>
                    <span class="btn delete">Delete</span>
                </li>
            </ul>

    <!-- /.modal -->
    <!--End Modal-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks @ManpreetSinghSandhu for your appreciation -:)

Comment: One small thing bro how are you appending the xml data into the modal.

Comment: you can review the changes... your xml value display in the modal box